# Do I need to register my mouseListener?

Tags: java, user-interface, mouselistener

I am supposed to have a GUI that keeps track of a list of pre-specified "special" points. If the user's mouse moves over one of these points, the point lights up. My task was to write the code that would go inside of the handler/listener below and use the references and also assume the existence of the method listed below (which I was supposed to invoke- assume it has already been written).

- specialPointList // an ArrayList of the pre-specified "special" points; the type is `ArrayList<Point>`
- assume this method exists: `public void lightUpAPoint(Point p)`

My code will go inside the handler method:

```
public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent event) {

}
```

Do I need to register my mouseListener?

This is what I believe the question is asking me to do:

```
public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent event) {
    specialPointList = ArrayList<Point>();

    Point mousePoint = event.getPoint(); 
    for(Point point : specialPointList) {
        if(mousePoint.equals(point)) {
            lightUpAPoint(point);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: *"Do I need to register my mouseListener?"* - Normally, yes, but *"My task was to write the code that would go inside of the handler/listener"* would suggest that the responsibility for actually registering the listener belongs to someone else .... also, it'd be useful if you checked to see if the `MouseEvent` fall within a `Point` before lighting it up

Comment: Yes, you need to. Independent of whatever component you are using, it will probably be component.addMouseListener(depends on your specific code);

Comment: @KrishnanshuGupta Given that this was the only information I was given and I can only write the code that would go inside the mouseMoved class, wouldn't it be the case that the previous comment states?

Comment: I have no idea what anybody else is talking about.  What you need to do to solve this is to you the Point of the mouse.  You get it using event.getLocationOnScreen() see https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/MouseEvent.html and then once you have the Point of the mouse, you can loop through that list of special Points and see if equal or close to equal.

Comment: @MadProgrammer Can you give me suggestion on how to do that?

Comment: @NickZiebert `locationOnScreen` is a bad idea, `MouseEvent`s are contextual to the container the container that created, simpler to just use `getPoint`

Comment: Start by having a look at [`MouseEvent#getPoint`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/event/MouseEvent.html#getPoint--), you need to check if the `x`/`y` positions are matching or not

Comment: @MadProgrammer yes, getPoint, good one.

Comment: I added the get point methods in the edits! But was the casting necessary

Comment: try this: Point mousePoint = event.getPoint();

Comment: @NickZiebert Did I add it at the right spot in the above edits?

Comment: @MadProgrammer Would adding the if statement from the above edits check if the x/y positions are matching?

Comment: @janny No, you're comparing memory references, which are highly unlikely to be the same `Point#equals` would be more suitable

Comment: @MadProgrammer I replaced it with .equals()! Is that what you meant?

Comment: @janny Yes......

Answer (score 0):

Whatever listener you create you need to register it to ui component.
Look at methods of component. If there is method to add your listener you can do it.

All swing components support MouseListener.

When action is made by user new event is created and is sent to your listener.